# Efficiently retrieving the latest row in an append-only table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Assuming we have an append-only table [1], in which each row is tagged with its commit timestamp and updates are INSERTs of a new row with the same ID but a new timestamp, are there some good ways of getting, for a given ID, the latest row with that ID? What would the SQL query look like [2]?

1: Example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE AppendOnlyTable (
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  Timestamp INT64 NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (ID, Timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table for your history that’s keyed by timestamp, make the timestamp key descending by adding the DESC keyword. Doing that makes reading all your history up to X-long-ago more efficient, since Spanner won't need to scan all your data to find out where X-long-ago begins, but can just begin reading "at the top".

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE AppendOnlyTable (
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  Timestamp INT64 NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (ID, Timestamp DESC);
```

The SQL query to fetch the latest row:

```
SELECT * From AppendOnlyTable WHERE UserId=12345 ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```